# Как создать char* через умные указатели

Tags: c++

Header file:

```
std::shared_ptr<char*> string;
```

Cpp file:

```
char* str = "hi!";
string = make_shared<char*>(str);
```

Поучаю ошибку: не существует подходящей функции преобразования из "std::shared_ptr<char *>" в "char *

Comment: а у Вас вот эта строка `char* str = "hi!";` компилируется? добавтье перед всеми char слово const - должно помочь.

Comment: @KoVadim Компилируется. Да, добавление const помогает, но я планирую в дальнейшем менять содержимое str, можно как-то это реализовать без const?

Comment: Вы понимаете, что у вас получается указатель на указатель? Может вам нужен просто `std::string`?

Comment: ну собственно я об этом и написал внизу

Answer (score 0):

Варианты:

```
    std::shared_ptr<const char*> string;
    const char* str = "hi!";
    string = make_shared<const char*>(str);
```

или

```
    std::shared_ptr<char*> string;
    char str[] = "hi!";
    string = make_shared<char*>(str);
```

Строковый литерал не может не быть `const`.

Вот только выглядит `shared_ptr<char*>` странно. Странно, чтоб не сказать большего. Зачем? Что вы хотите этим добиться?

Answer (score 0):

Первый способ

```
std::shared_ptr<const char*> string;

const char* str = "hi!";
string = make_shared<const char*>(str);
```

Второй способ пофиксить - использоваться с++ подходы - `std::string`

```
const char* str = "hi!";
std::shared_ptr<std::string> sstr = std::make_shared<std::string>(str);
```

а если где то понадобится именно указатель на char, тогда вот так `sstr->c_str();`

А возможно, Вам просто нужна обычная строка `std::string`.